# Trying to print object description in Xcode produces an Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, debugging

I have an objective-C object that we can call ObjCObj
I implemented a simple description method that usually works perfectly fine if I instanciate the class in a local variable.

The problem:
I iterate through an array of ObjCObj objects and put them into a Swift Array

```
let cacheArray = [ObjCObj]()
```

After my array is filled, I try set a breakpoint, try to print the value of an Item and I get the following error:

```
expression produced error: 

/var/folders/w9/3rvg1bk95379dgvcr11n16_h0000gp/T/lldb/3499/expr878.swift:1:46: error: use of undeclared type '__ObjC'
$__lldb__DumpForDebugger(Swift.UnsafePointer<__ObjC.ObjCObj>(bitPattern: 0x67fd9b0).memory)
```

If I try to print an Expression like:

```
cacheArray[2]
```

It works. But If I open the array in the debugger inspector and choose one line of the array and ask for printing the description, it fails.

Comment: Hi @Mikael, running into something similar myself. Did you find any resolution/workaround for this?

Comment: For now, I implement debugDescription in my objects to display the information I need. I also directly access the objects properties in the console. po myarray.count or things like that.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same error only moments ago and tracked it down to a bad property attribute in one of my Obj-C Mantle model classes. (Incorrectly treated an object as a scalar.)

Broken:

```
@property(nonatomic, assign, readonly, nullable) AdditionalInformationStatus *additionalInformationStatus;
                     ^^^^^^
```

Fixed:

```
@property(nonatomic, copy, readonly, nullable) AdditionalInformationStatus *additionalInformationStatus;
                     ^^^^
```

It was an easy fix, but tough to track down.

Comment: well, I don't know why we should have to change this property in order for xcode to simply print a variable :/

Comment: This wasn't just preventing me from printing values, it was also crashing our app. When I added a breakpoint to interrogate the value, I got the same error you received. When I zeroed in on the problem, it was clearly a mistake on our part. We intended to retain a copy of the object, but instead we did a simple assign as one would for a delegate, which meant our object reference count did not increase, which caused it to be deallocated, which caused the crash... (and the unhelpful error message above)

Comment: Disabling the Addess Sanitizer solves the problem apparently. Not for all situation though.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a bug.  Please file it at http://bugreporter.apple.com.

Comment: Was this a bug?